# TypeError: Cannot read property 'extract' of undefined Joi npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, joi

Hi I am trying to access the username property, but it give me this error Type Error: Cannot read property 'extract' of undefined
here is my current code. I am using a *Joi package*

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
state = {
    account: { username: "", password: "" },
    errors: {},
};
validate = () => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().required().label("Username"),
        password: Joi.string().required().label("Password"),
    });
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = schema.validate(this.state.account, options);

    if (!error) return null;

    const errors = {};
    error.details.map((item) => (errors[item.path[0]] = item.message));
    console.log(error.details);
    return errors;
};
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;

    console.log("Submitted");
};
validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };

    const schemaOfProperty = Joi.object({
        [name]: this.schema.extract(name),
    });

    const { error } = schemaOfProperty.validate(obj);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
};
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where `this.schema` is declared or defined. Seems the error is accurate that `this.schema` is undefined.

Comment: Hi Drew , thanks for the response, here where i declare the schema ----
![schema](https://imgur.com/W61FQyE.jpg)

Comment: That's *a* `schema` but it isn't `this.schema`. Did you mean to say `this.schema = Joi.object({......});`?

Comment: **this.schema = Joi.object({......});** works but error got remove only once you submit the form. i think i dunno how implement it properly, i also trying to use the extract method in Joi docs. didn't help me .

Answer (score 0):

import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';

instead of
import Joi from "@hapi/joi";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).